# UIWebview loadRequest not loading when called from another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

When my web viewDidLoad fires it correctly sets the starting URL for my web view and logs "Load Request: http://xxxxxx.dev/login". Just as you would expect.

When calling loadRequestFromString from SidebarViewController, the webview does not change to the correct URL. However, thanks to NSLog I can see that it is getting to that point just not refreshing the URL "Load Request: http://xxxxxx.dev/this-is-the-url-that-should-load".

**SidebarViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSString *url = self.tableData[indexPath.row][@"url"];

    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];

    WebAppViewController *wvc = [[WebAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"webappController" bundle:kNilOptions];
    [wvc loadRequestFromString:url];
}
```

**WebAppViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self loadRequestFromString:@"http://xxxxxx.dev/login"];
}

.....

- (void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString
{

    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"Load Request: %@", urlString);

    NSString *properlyEscapedURL = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:properlyEscapedURL];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

}
```

Comment: Why you are calling same method from another class as well as from viewDidLoad? This method must be getting called twice??

Comment: Do you not already have the WebAppViewController as one of the controllers in your hierarchy (I assume you're using the SWRevealViewController)? If so, then you should be getting a reference to the one you have, not creating a new one with alloc initWithNibName:bundle:.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I am using SWRevealViewController. I'm really new to iOS development so I'm not sure what you mean by getting a reference. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: A reference means a pointer to the object. For instance, if your controller is embedded in a navigation controller, you can get a reference to the navigation controller with self.navigationController. The SWRevealViewController has properties revealViewController, frontViewController, rearViewController, and rightViewController that all point to controllers in its hierarchy. You need to use one (or a combination) of these to get references to what you want. I can't give you more specific advice without knowing where your 2 controllers fit into that scheme.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for your response. I based my storyboard off of the example provided with SWRevealViewController (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerStoryboardExample). I guess I'm confused because I can see in the log that [wvc loadRequestFromString:url] in SidebarViewController.m successfully calls loadRequestFromString in WebAppViewController.m. It just doesn't change the active URL of the webview.